# Width and height of a TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield

When I add a TextField on my stage in my Flash project, I have to choose the size (width and height) of the field. If, with programming, I modify that text, I would like that TextField to resize and have the height it needs.

In particular, I am developing a chat application and I would like to wrap every message with typical bubble, but the length of that message may be whatever. In HTML it would be very easy, for example.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the autoSize property of the `TextField`

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#autoSize

For Example:

```
myTextField.autoSize = "left"
```

> If autoSize is set to TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT, the text is treated as
>   left-justified text, meaning that the left margin of the text field
>   remains fixed and any resizing of a single line of the text field is
>   on the right margin. If the text includes a line break (for example,
>   "\n" or "\r"), the bottom is also resized to fit the next line of
>   text.

Comment: Should I include `wordWrap` too?

Comment: Only if word wrapping fits the style you are looking for, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For more accurate width/height detection use [TextLineMetrics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html)

[image]